# NSNotificationCenter in viewDidLoad: not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

for some reason this code isn't working in `viewDidLoad`, but will work in `viewWillAppear`. Any ideas?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
           addObserver:self 
              selector:@selector(wakeUp:)
                  name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                object:nil];
```

Thank you

Comment: So, have you put your application into background by pressing the home button once the app was running, and brought it back into foreground by tapping its icon ? And do you have a method `- (void)wakeUp:(NSNotification *)notification` ? Because it should work just fine.

Comment: yup, ive tried all that. and to add fuel to the fire I put the exact same code in viewWillAppear and it works. wtf?

Comment: You already said `viewWillAppear:`; you mean `viewDidAppear:` this time? You're going to have to describe some symptoms. There must be something else going on that is either causing this to appear to not work, or causing the other calls to appear to work. Are you _sure_ that when you move this code around, that there is one and only one place this notification registration is taking place?

Comment: it works in viewWillAppear, it does not in viewDidLoad. As far as I can tell there is no funny business going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're definitely sure `viewDidLoad` is being invoked?

Comment: yup, set up an nslog and everything

Comment: Is your removeObserver: being run accidentally?

Comment: lol wow that was a stupid mistake. thank you! now im going to make sure i always remove observer with a name

Comment: well--i'd say be careful where you put the remove observer call. you could use -viewDidUnload: and/or -dealloc perhaps. glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

For my case is that I put the `removeObserver` method inside `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method, and if I take a picture or do something else, this method fires out of my expect. So, now I always remove notification observer at `dealloc` stage.